# Python pathos mutiprocessing, one list and one object as arguments

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I want to use multiprocessing to accelerate multiple calls to a function, the function takes as argument two values, a variable that changes for every calculation and a constant variable.

Here is a code that emulates my problem:

```
import pathos.pools as pp
p = pp.ProcessPool(4)

def add(x,y):
   return x+y

x = [0,1,2,3]
y = 5

result = p.map(add, x, y)
```

As y is not a list I get the following error:

```
TypeError: izip argument #2 must support iteration
```

In this simple case the straightforward solution would be to make `y` a list of the constant values:

```
y = [5 for value in x]
```

But I would like to avoid this solution as in my case y is a complex object that takes up quite a big chunk of memory.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Could you please be more clear about what you need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

you can just use local variables for the function you declare. I often make a wrapper to pass non-iterables, e.g.

```
def add(x,y):
    return x+y

def add_wrapper(x):
    y = 5
    return add(x,y)

x = [0,1,2,3]
result = p.map(add_wrapper, x)
```

or

```
def add(x,y):
    return x+y

def add_wrapper(x):
    return add(x,y)

y = 5
x = [0,1,2,3]
result = p.map(add_wrapper, x)
```